# Should I use cache partition or cache partitioning to name a technique

Tags: phrases, programming

The "cache partition technique" is a technique that divides the cache into the equal-size cache partitions.

I'm not sure if I should call it "cache partition technique" or "cache partitioning technique".

My intuition told me I should use "cache partitioning technique" but I'm not that sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "Cache partitioning technique", **you describe the technique in a generalized manner by telling its major feature wherein you do not specify the name of the technique.**

If I try to elaborate upon the citation you provided in the question - Cache partitioning technique may have (in a generalized way) a major feature where the (memory) cache is divided into partitions (regions). Additionally, each partition may hold a unique set of data which is queried over the network layer. We can generally refer to the technique by virtue of its highlight (which is to divide the cache into partition) so that laymen can understand the intent of the mention.

Whereas, when you say "the cache partition technique" you actually specify the nomenclature of a particular technique, assuming the (a much more technical) audience would know its salient features.

This is same as when "The Theory of Gravitation" could be generally referred to as the theory of attracting objects